# Hacer funcionar el siguiente proyecto en python

Tags: python

estoy intentando arrancar el siguiento proyecto:

[proyecto que intento arrancar](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/pyvoicechanger)

Basicamente lo que hago es arrancar el pyvoicechanger.py:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me muestra siempre el mismo error:

> C:\Users\Desktop\New folder
>   (3)\pyvoicechanger-master\pyvoicechanger-m
>   ster\build\scripts-3.5>python3.5 pyvoicechanger.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "pyvoicechanger.py", line 19, in 
>       from anglerfish import (check_encoding, make_logger, make_post_exec_msg, ImportError: No module named 'anglerfish'

Instale las librerías y no entiendo a que se deba, en mi caso estoy usando python 3.5 y busque el modulo pero no consegui solucionarlo.

Comment: Por lo que se ve en el repositorio está pensado para trabajar sobre un entorno linux y veo que tu estás desde windows

Comment: si pero sox es multiplataforma, pyqt funciona en windows, en general debería funcionar en windows también. es solo un script .py que usa esas dependencias.

Comment: ¿Ya instalaste mediante el gestor de paquetes de python (pip) el módulo de *anglerfish*?

Comment: me lo descargo de aquí https://pypi.python.org/pypi/anglerfish/2.2.0 y pongo pip install anglerfish-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl ?¿

Comment: Solo intenta con `pip install anglerfish`